# C++ - Method with multiple parameter types

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

I've a lot of Java experience but new to C++.

I need to have a method, simple example is of set union, that will work with parameters of `set<int>` and of `set<bool>`, but no other types.

At the moment I have overloaded the method name, but it duplicates a lot of similar code in the method body.

Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a method that "will not work with other types" ? Is it really a problem if `SetUnion<set<short> >` compiles?

Comment: There is a `std::set_union` already implemented in the standard library. It might look strange in the beginning, considering that the arguments are not *sets* (rather iterators) but it is a sound idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a **[Function Template](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGQQFjAC&url=http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/function_templates.htm&ei=E4_pT9KBEobxrQedq_yaDg&usg=AFQjCNFHb1LeZKs06Y7blLluXdxAKHuVbQ)** .
But you can do that if you are performing similar operations regardless of the type of arguments. If you are performing different operations for each of data types then you will have to specialize the template function which basically brings you back to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T>
void func(const std::set<T> &param)
{
  // your staff
}

//....

int main()
{
  std::set<int> int_set;
  std::set<bool> bool_set;

  func(int_set);
  func(bool_set);
}
```

Comment: I think OP only wants to allow `std::set<int>` and `std::set<bool>`, so some extra template magic is needed.